# How to Query deep nested json in Node?

Tags: node.js, json

I have a sample JSON here and wanted to get the number of developers in company using node.

```
var data = {
         "company": {
      "unit-1":{
          "people":[
               {"person":"developer-1"},
               {"person":"developer-2"},
               {"person":"developer-3"}
          ]
        
      },
      "unit-2":{
          "people":[
                {"person":"developer-8"},
                {"person":"developer-9"},
                {"person":"developer-10"}
          ]
      }
    
   }}
```

I have used the npm json-query package to query the deepest part of the json.

```
var jsonQuery = require('json-query')
var countDev = 0 
var result = jsonQuery('company[**][*people]', {data: data}).value 
result.forEach(peep =>{
countDev+=1
})

console.log(`Company two has ${countDev} developers!`)
```

The output is AS expected but the only problem here, is that I want to access through the deepest key i.e `person` in this case . How can I access it without going through the key `people`
and get developers directly.

Any other idea or library will be appreciated.
Here below is the result logged .

```
    result = [
  { person: 'developer-1' },
  { person: 'developer-2' },
  { person: 'developer-3' },
  { person: 'developer-8' },
  { person: 'developer-9' },
  { person: 'developer-10' }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure JavaScript and without using any module the solution would be something like this

```
let res = [];
for(val in data.company) res = [...res, ...data.company[val].people]
console.log(res)
```

note that for big objects this would have a poor performance,
this would have a better performance:

```
const keys = Object.keys(data.company);
let res = [];
for(let i = 0, n = keys.length; i < n; i++){
   res = [...res, ...data.company[keys[i]].people ]
}
```